# Unit testing C# using ContentResult type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this action of a controller in mvc.net c#

```
public ContentResult GetVariableMapKml(string variableId, string sitesIds, string beginDate, string endDate, int limit)
    {
        Object resultData = null;
        // Prepare specific Json configuration
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        if (variableId != null && variableId != "")
        {
           ...
            if (valuesList != null)
            {
                resultData = new
                {
                    Values = valuesList,
                    Units = varUnits
                };
            }
            else
            {
               resultData = new
               {
                   Error = "Error at GetVariableMapKml() method: Null params"
               };
            }

        }

        var result = new ContentResult
        {
            Content = serializer.Serialize(resultData),
            ContentType = "application/json"
        };

        return result;
    }
```

I'm doing a unit test in c and I need to access the result of ContentResult, to check if the variable Error is null.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void GetVariableMapKmlWrongParams()
    {
        FieldDataController controller = new FieldDataController();
        controller.ControllerContext =  
        TestUtils.CreateMockSessionControllerContext().Object as ControllerContext;

        //param null
        ContentResult result = controller.GetVariableMapKml(null, null, "05/05/2001", 
                                                            "02/10/2012", 100);
        Assert.IsNotNull("Error");
    }
```

How I can access to Error content and check if this content is null? Thank you.

Comment: Your method returns a ContentResult object.  Check that.

Comment: In the Content Object Variable is a variable named Error or Values​​. I want to check that in the Conten object there are the variable Error and there are not the variable Values.

Comment: @juanchoelx: So do that - deserialize `result.Content`,  and check it...

Comment: How I can deserialize the result Content? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetVariableMapKmlWrongParams()
    {
        FieldDataController controller = new FieldDataController();
        controller.ControllerContext =
        TestUtils.CreateMockSessionControllerContext().Object as ControllerContext;

        //param null
        ContentResult result = controller.GetVariableMapKml(null, null, "05/05/2001",
                                                            "02/10/2012", 100);

        var returnedObject = (Dictionary<string, object>)(new JavaScriptSerializer()).DeserializeObject(result.Content);

        Assert.IsTrue(returnedObject.ContainsKey("Error"));

    }
```

You can test the dictionary object for the presence of keys and their values